# Monitoring of network traffic

Tags: java, networking

Can I create on Java monitoring program of network traffic? The program must control all network traffic which goes from computer program (including OS modules) to Network driver and back. If yes, How?

**NOTE:**

I want not only to monitor traffic also to control it. I want to implement such system on windows NT. It cannot be fulfilled o purely on Java. How can I perform it with the help of JNI?

Or maybe another variant. I am not acquaint with windows services, but still. I will write a program on C++ and register it as windows service. Then I call from my Java application this service (I don't know how to do this) and request network traffic. On the C++ program part all the traffic will be blocked if there is no Java program (or it doesn't request traffic); on the other way transmitted to this program. May be the java part can be implemented and work on an Java server (Glass Fish, JBoss). The C++ part in turn will transmit traffic to localhost.

What do you think about these ways?

Comment: which OS do you want to build this for?

Comment: I want to it on windows NT, particular Windows 7.

Comment: You want to control the traffic, or monitor it?  These are two very different things...

Comment: Not very different. Nevertheless, the idea is to be a kind of medium between network adapter (driver) and software which requires network activity.

Comment: @itun *Very* different. You can monitor the traffic with any of several versions of JPcap. However there is no way in Java you can *control* it.

Comment: What if I make local server on Java and in windows setup it as a proxy server, do I control traffic in this way?

Comment: @itun That won't satisfy your requirement for all traffic, only the traffic that you can force to go via your proxy.

Comment: What traffic is going through proxy server? I have heard that all. Since a proxy server becomes the media between client and the others members of a network.

Comment: @itun No. A proxy only handles a specific protocol. You have HTTP proxies, SOCKS proxies, ... So any specific proxy only sees the traffic for its ow protocol, and that is only for applications or services that have been configured to use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When *"monitoring of network traffic"* then [*pcap*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap), I'd say.

Googling *"pcap java"* brought me that as first hit: [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/).

Did not test it, but pcap is the standard solution for native C programs. Cannot tell if the Java wrapper is good, but at least its website looks nice. ;-)