# How to find a process that is currently listening at an active port(using Java)

Tags: java

For a port on which connection has been established, can the process be found out involved in the connection? eg. if there is a call on Skype, then communication will be established at a certain port/s. Can these details be captured and event of a call made/received using Skype be distinguished?
Note: This has to be done using Java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8044678/106261

Comment: You can't do that with plain Java. This requires platform depedent extension and JNI libraries (native code).

Comment: @Robert can u direct me to the APIs and technologies which can be used to achieve this?

Comment: That depends on the platform you are developing for. You have to find existing JNI libraries or develop them on your own (C/C++).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `ServerSocket`. You can find an explanation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

Comment: I am using Server Socket currently. But creating a socket is only telling me whether the port is in use or not. How can the process which is using this port be identified? Even a PID is sufficient.