# Trigger Java Code When a specified Webpage is called on the local maschine

Tags: java, sockets, http

I want to run Java Code on local Machine if a specified Webpage is called (HTTP request).

For example I am opening https://stackoverflow.com/, then I want my Java code to be triggered and this code opens some directories.

Is that even possible ?

Maybe with Sockets or is it possible to analyse the http Transfer with Java ?
I could not find a solution, please help.

Comment: What does "open a directory" mean? Do you mean to open windows explorer at that directory?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to open a Directory in Windows Explorer, if a certain page is opened.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

You could create a monitor that looks http traffic and detect requests to the desired site using pcap or the java wrapper [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/).

Related to: [Monitoring of network traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044623/monitoring-of-network-traffic)

Also other way is to create a java http proxy that analyzes the data flow before forward the request and configure it as your system proxy